# With Durandal: all my menus using the same viewModel are selected (isActive)

Tags: durandal, sammy.js

I am working on an asp.net MVC with the **Durandal** Template. This Durandal Template uses the Sammy routing solution.

I would like to have my left menu to reflect visible routes as showed on the picture below:

[image]

The picture above is what I would like to obtain (this is not what I have so far).

The particularity of my solution is that every route should be the same. I mean: every route is pointing to 'viewmodels/searchTransport' and I would like to use a parameter to filter my search.

So I would like to have a unique view/viewModel but use them with a kind of filter to... filter elements already invoiced, in progress...

Here is my first thought:

```
    var routes = [
    { url: 'searchTransport',     moduleId: 'viewmodels/searchTransport', name: resource.advancedSearch, visible: true, settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'all' } },
    { url: 'inProgressTransport', moduleId: 'viewmodels/searchTransport', name: resource.inProgress, visible: true, settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'inProgress'  } },
    { url: 'finishedTransport',   moduleId: 'viewmodels/searchTransport', name: resource.finished, visible: true, settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'finished'  } },
    { url: 'invoicedTransport',   moduleId: 'viewmodels/searchTransport', name: resource.invoiced, visible: true, settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'invoiced'  } },
    { url: 'flaggedTransport',    moduleId: 'viewmodels/searchTransport', name: resource.flagged, visible: true, settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'flagged' } },
```

This menu is displayed in my shell.html like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
    <li data-bind="css: { menuActive: isActive }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: name"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The problem:** my left menu is displayed with all the routes as `isActive` because all these routes ause using the same moduleId. And thus all the elements in my menu are selected (blank background, see picture below). This is not what I need; I would like to select only the element with the current filter applied.

**Question:** how to organize my routes to be able to reuse the same routes but with a different parameter for each and have the ability to select only one of them in my left side menu?

I hope I'm clear, otherwize I'll try to clarify.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this question?  I am having the same issue with a project that I am working on.

Comment: @mcottingham: please see my answer. It this is not clear, ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
var routes = [
    // Custom
    { url: 'welcome',       moduleId: 'viewmodels/general/welcome',     name: rscMenu.welcome,      visible: true, settings: {} },
    { url: 'userProfile',   moduleId: 'viewmodels/general/userProfile', name: rscMenu.userProfile,  visible: true, settings: {} },
    // Transport        
    { url: 'generalTransport/:idTran',        moduleId: 'viewmodels/transport/generalTransport',  name: rscMenu.newTransport,    visible: false, settings: { transport: true } },
    { url: 'searchTransport/latestTransport', moduleId: 'viewmodels/transport/searchTransport',   name: rscMenu.latestTransport, visible: true,  settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'latestTransport' } },
    { url: 'searchTransport/inProgress',      moduleId: 'viewmodels/transport/searchTransport',   name: rscMenu.inProgress,      visible: true,  settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'inProgress' } },
    { url: 'searchTransport/finished',        moduleId: 'viewmodels/transport/searchTransport',   name: rscMenu.finished,        visible: true,  settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'finished' } },
    { url: 'searchTransport/invoiced',        moduleId: 'viewmodels/transport/searchTransport',   name: rscMenu.invoiced,        visible: true,  settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'invoiced' } },
    { url: 'searchTransport/flagged',         moduleId: 'viewmodels/transport/searchTransport',   name: rscMenu.flagged,         visible: true,  settings: { transport: true, initValue: 'flagged' } },
    ...
```

Below is my shell viewModel:

```
define(function(require) {

var router = require('durandal/plugins/router'),
    system = require('durandal/system'),
    app = require('durandal/app'),
    logger = require('services/logger'),
    datacontext = require('services/datacontext'),
    config = require('modules/config'),
    rscMenu = require('modules/i18n!nls/menuResource');

var transportRoutes = ko.computed(function () {
        return router.allRoutes().filter(function (r) {
            return r.visible && r.settings.transport;
        });
});
...
```

Below is my shell view:

```
    <div class="page-sidebar">
        <ul class="accordion" data-role="accordion" data-bind="accordion: {}">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <ul class="sub-menu light" data-bind="foreach: transportRoutes">
                        <li data-bind="css: { menuActive: (url == $parent.router.activeRoute().url) }, attr: { id: settings.initValue }">
                            <a data-bind="attr: { href: (settings.initValue) ? hash.replace(':initValue', settings.initValue) : hash }, html: name"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        ...
```

The trick for selecting the right element in the sidebar (according to the current view) is located in the shell view with this `css: { menuActive: (url == $parent.router.activeRoute().url) }`.

Hope it helps someone someday.

Comment: +1... Thanks so much for posting this, I'd been struggling with this issue too, the answer seems so obvious once you see it.